# KeyboardShrinksView & Keyboard.shrinkView(true) have no effect on iOS with Cordova 3.4.1 + Keyboard plugin

Tags: ios, mobile, cordova, keyboard

I'm using Cordova 3.4.1 and [the Keyboard plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard) from [cordova-plugins](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins).  According to the Keyboard plugin's docs, I should be able to set the `<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />` preference or call `Keyboard.shrinkView(true)` in my Javascript to make the keyboard, uh, shrink the view.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, neither of these has any effect, and I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.  I'd appreciate any help that anyone can provide in getting this to work as advertised.

I'm not sure what bits of configuration or code would be useful for me to provide for debugging purposes.  Here's the `config.xml` for the iOS build:

https://gist.github.com/mccutchen/3fd6c3f1d4096a348a00

This question is asking much the same thing, but does not yet have any useful answers:

[PhoneGap 3.3 iOS KeyboardShrinksView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739396/phonegap-3-3-ios-keyboardshrinksview)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with latest cordova + this plugin on iOS 8.1. Have you found a solution since June ?

Answer (score 0):

see my reply to this SO article for some possible help/insight on this (still unresolved AFAIK) topic: [Phonegap KeyboardShrinksView and position fixed on iOS not applying correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223617/phonegap-keyboardshrinksview-and-position-fixed-on-ios-not-applying-correctly/21934366#21934366)